# Perl: Dump data from a hash into excel

Tags: arrays, excel, perl, hash

I have a hash with key and Values(array). I want to dump them to a spreadsheet, but having difficulty in arranging them .

%hash 
key1 -> foo bar 
key2-> john adam gill 
key3-> apple banana mango orange

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $pattern = "BEGIN_";
my $format;
my @keys = qw(key1 key2 key3);
foreach my $key(@keys){
     open my $fh, "<","filename.txt" or die $!;
      while ( <$fh> ) {
        if (/$pattern/) {
        push(@matching_lines, $_);
      }
    }
    $hash{$key} = [@matching_lines] ; 
   for (@matching_lines) { $_ = undef } ; #Emptying the array contents,to reuse it for for all the other keys
}

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'c:\TEMP\filename.xlsx' ); 
 if (not defined $workbook)
{
    die "Failed to create spreadsheet: $!";
}
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

#  Add and define a format
$format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_bg_color( 'yellow' );

my $row = 1;
my $col = 0;

foreach my $k (keys %hash)
{
     $worksheet->write($row, $col, $k, $format); # title
     $worksheet->write_col($row+1, $col, $hash{$k}); #value
     $col++;
}
$workbook->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";
```

**Current Output**

[image]
**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: There are some typos in your example. There's a `my` missing, and the use of `%hash` and `%tools` doesn't make sense. I fixed those and ran it, which gave me the correct output, but row 1 and column A are empty. It starts in B2, but looks completely correct. I think your [mcve] does something else as your real code.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for pointing out the typos. I have corrected them. I have double checked my code and ran again and still the output is same as the current output mentioned above. Not sure, what am I missing

Comment: Can you include a `print $row . "\n";` inside your loop to verify that `$row` isn't being incremented?

Comment: @Mr.Llama That gave me output `1 1 1`. `$row` isn't incremented, thats the reason the heading (`key2` and `key 3`)is printing correctly . But why only values are getting space. I tried printing the hash outside the excel and the values came out without any spaces

Comment: Can you add `use Data::Dumper;` to the start of your script and include `print Dumper($hash);` before the foreach loop?

Comment: @Mr.Llama I agree, the data must be wrong. OP should [edit] the question and include the real content of `%hash`, the pseudo-description at the top of the question is useless. I have used `my %hash = (
    key1 => [qw/foo bar/],
    key2 => [qw/john adam gill/],
    key3 => [qw/apple banana mango orango/],
);
`, which obviously works. I think there are `undef`s in the data structure.

Comment: @Mr.Llama added the code in which I am forming the hash

Comment: You're not clearing `@matching_lines` correctly so it ends up having `undef` entries instead of being empty: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36603758/477563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not correctly emptying your `@matching_lines` array.  This line:

```
for (@matching_lines) { $_ = undef }
```

Sets the array values to `undef`, but *does not remove them*.
For example, if `@matching_lines` was `('foo', 'bar')`, now it becomes `(undef, undef)`.  When you add `baz` and `qux` to it later, it becomes `(undef, undef, 'baz', 'qux')`.  These `undef`s become blank cells when you add them to the worksheet.

To correctly empty the array, use:

```
@matching_lines = ();
```

Comment: Yep. Worked perfectly. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Now you've actually updated your program to clarify that the problem is how you're reading your data, the below is moot. But it does illustrate an alternative approach.

OK, the core problem here is what you're trying to do is 'flip' a hash. You're printing row by row, but your hash is organised in columns.

Using comma sep as a quick proxy for printing actual excel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

#initialise
my %hash = (
    key1 => [qw (  foo bar  )],
    key2 => [qw (  john adam gill  )],
    key3 => [qw (  apple banana mango orange )],
);

#print for debug
print Dumper \%hash;


#get header row. Sort it, because hashes are unordered.
#could instead:
#my @keys = qw ( key1 key2 key3 );
my @keys = sort keys %hash;
#print header row
print join ",", @keys, "\n";

#iterate until every element of the hash is gone
while ( map { @{ $hash{$_} } } @keys ) {
    #cycle the keys, shifting a value of the top of each array. 
    #replace any undefined values with ''. 
    print shift( @{ $hash{$_} } ) // '', "," for @keys;
    print "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
key1,key2,key3,
foo,john,apple,
bar,adam,banana,
,gill,mango,
,,orange,
```

Which if you load it as `csv` into Excel, should give your desired result. I'm pretty sure you could use a similar 'write row' with the module.

So this actually seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/env/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

#initialise
my %hash = (
    key1 => [qw (  foo bar  )],
    key2 => [qw (  john adam gill  )],
    key3 => [qw (  apple banana mango orange )],
);


my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('c:\TEMP\filename.xlsx');
if ( not defined $workbook ) {
    die "Failed to create spreadsheet: $!";
}
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

#  Add and define a format
my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_bg_color('yellow');

my @keys = sort keys %hash;
my $row  = 0;
$worksheet->write_row( $row++, 0, \@keys, $format );
while ( map { @{ $hash{$_} } } @keys ) {
    my $col = 0;
    $worksheet->write( $row, $col++, shift( @{ $hash{$_} } ) // '' )
        for @keys;
    $row++;
}
$workbook->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";
```

[image: Output]